# Forced code pruning, C-style macros in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

Writing an ES app for three very different platforms that share 80% of their logic.

Wish to use Webpack to package only required modules - which means dynamic imports are no use.

Without having three separate configurations for Webpack.

Is there a plugin for Webpack that works like [macros in C processors](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html)?

Something that combines the features of the [DotEnv plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) and [tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)?

This is something I'm prepared to write but my app has a deadline enforced by a real world event.

I'm looking at NormalModuleReplacementPlugin as [described here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/decreasing-webpack-bundle-size-with-conditional-imports-f8bb94db8195) but alternatives welcomed.

Comment: Im not sure what you want, but maybe you can leverage [webpack tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)

Comment: There is [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/). It is used by dotenv plugin. Tree-shaking is performed by webpack in production builds, its a core webpack functionality.

Comment: I should have mentioned `import`s in the question, which only said "Wish to use Webpack to package only required modules."